# how to use display with if function?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show the p element with `id=ex2` red if the color of `p` element with  `id=ex1` is red. I have tried but failed. Please help.

```
<p id="ex1" style="color: red;">red</p>
<p id="ex2">f</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myElement = document.getElementById('ex1');
    if (myElement.style.color = red){
        document.getElementById('ex2').innerHTML = 'red';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Watch your `if` condition! `=` is the [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators), `==` is the [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). They are different things with different effects. `red` is a variable, you probably want the [string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) `'red'`.

Comment: `console.log(myElement.style.color)` and `red` is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some typos in your code. To set the color property you have to use `style.color` on the element like you did to get the color. But you are using `innerHTML` which is used to set or return the HTML content (inner HTML) of an element.  Try the following:

```js
var myElement = document.getElementById('ex1');
var color = myElement.style.color;
if ( color == 'red'){
    document.getElementById('ex2').style.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
<p id="ex1" style="color: red;">red</p>
<p id="ex2">f</p>
```

Comment: Mr. Mamum, your code is working...

Comment: @SuparnoSengupta, you are most welcome. Please accept the answer if it helps.....thanks.